# javascript detect if the user liked a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I've searched before asking, but couldn't find a suitable answer .

The scenario is the following , **I have a page on my site with download button**, so i want the user to like the page to enable the download button, So the button is disabled by default and will be enabled when the user like the page, No security risk if the user manipulated the HTML in any inspector .

I already know that I can use the event "edge.create" to know that the user just liked this page, but the problem will appear in his next visit, the button will be disabled while he already liked the page in a previous visit, cookies will be quirky unstable solution .

**I prefer a solution that doesn't depend on user login**, I don't want to force users to login using Facebook, Hacks and tricky solutions are accepted .

**NOT Duplicate** as The other topic talks about facebook tab app (Canvas), I'm talking about Like button on my own site, and the required solution must be only in Javascript and doesn't require users to login
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a button that says "did you like my page", and if they click that button ***then*** show the download button.

Comment: @Thew The link you wrote is talking about tab app while I'm talking about an article or download item within my site

Comment: @adeneo I want Facebook Like button, not a normal button :)